# SharePoint Search Center's Search navigation

Tags: sharepoint-2013

In sharepoint 2013 Standard On premises, I configured the Enterprise Search Center.
In the Enterprise Search Center's Default.aspx page, I added Search Navigation Web Part.
However the step of the addition is successfully and can display navigation web part in the default.aspx page, Navigation Links(Everythins, People, Video,...) cannot activate.
I usually click the click but this link cannot work and cannot redirect to the specified link properly.

How can I work around for this?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the control settings by editing the navigation webpart. It should be set to Default. You could also check the search settings options under Site settings -> Search -> Search settings and check if the navigation links are correctly linked to the desired results page.